# Accidentally sent 0.036 tbtc to the tbtc token address, theoretically recoverable?

Tags: transactions

Proof:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x8daebade922df735c38c80c7ebd708af50815faa?a=0x6146d84fbf376c3f51131c7fec144c32e6f7a6bd

transaction hash
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b3b6a563f794d1d3a534992fe1df961614af3059673701b5eaed11b4b662a4c

Is the value recoverable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transaction shows that you sent 0.036 tBTC to [0x6146D84fBF376C3f51131C7FEC144c32E6F7A6bD](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6146D84fBF376C3f51131C7FEC144c32E6F7A6bD), which is an EOA (externally owned account—just a normal user account), not a token contract.